# I have a bunch of GIF images on a single page. How to prevent (JQuery) action for all of them?

Tags: jquery, image, onclick, gif, animated-gif

My problem is when i try to Reload/Reset the Animated GIF so like that when you click over the static image it will play the animated image from the beginning like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('img.badge-item-animated-img').attr('src', src);
```

It is working but the action is occurring for all of the images that i have in my page.

How can i make it happen only for the one that I'm clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going up from current element, then looking within that parent for all the images.... you only want to `find` within the current element

Change to:

```
/* find within "this"*/
$(this).find('img.badge-item-animated-img').attr('src', src);
```

Edit: clcik on jpg, change src of GIF:

```
$('.badge-item-img').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().find('img.badge-item-animated-img').attr('src',function(i,src){
         /* replace src with same vale so GIF refreshes*/
         return src;
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes but when i click to the second (POST) image which also have an static and a gif image... it returns the url of the first post GIF intead of the actual that I'm clicking

Comment: same thing...put the first line inside the click handler so you only look for that image src

Comment: I did it but its now working... still returning with the gif image of the first post instead of the one than I'm clicking.

Comment: I just edited the HTML code so you have an idea of what i'm talking about check it out.

Comment: OK... you want to switch `jpg` for `gif` ? Explain full behavior. Also, can you wrap each set? Not critical but makes code nice an clean

Comment: What im trying to do with the src is to reload / re- add the animated gif so like that every time i click my static image JPG i will see the animated gif from the beginning.

Comment: Cos my animated image GIF is hidden with css display:none; but is playing in the background and by the time i click my static img to switch to the animated it will be already running instead of start from the beginning

Comment: Excelent my friend! you are a life saver! I got it working now! Thank you so much! Happy thanks giving! ;)